# API/ code for displaying navigation

Tags: javascript, html, gps

Is there any API/code in java/javascript/html with which I could display my navigation using GPS/HTML5 Geolocation API as the Google Navigation do?

Answer (score 0):

Google maps exposes an api you can use https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: If I updates my position continuously to the JavaScript API, can I have the navigation?

Comment: for directions specific stuff, look at this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: let me have a look on that. Anyways Thank You for your help.

Comment: My requirement is to get navigation and not direction. Can you please help me on that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: can you explain the difference? Do you mean the ability to move around the map? Or do you mean step by step navigation (directions)

Comment: I have the positions of source and destination. I need to display the route in the map and the arrow should travel along as I move to the destination, Just as Google Navigation do.

Comment: you may be out of luck. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/cLT9lCEUTic